# PHP shortcode condition not work

Tags: php, shortcode

I'm using this below example code:

```
<?php
$id = "a";
echo $id == "a" ? "Apple" : $id == "b" ? "Bat" : $id == "c" ? "Cat" : $id == "d" ? "Dog" : "Others";
```

I want to get output as **Apple**. But i got **Dog**. Any one can please help me.

Comment: If you read the manual you'll see that this is mentioned very explicitly: http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php

Comment: That's the problem with code obfuscation, it makes code harder to read ;-P

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?php

$id = "a";

echo $id == "a" ? "Apple" : ($id == "b" ? "Bat" : ($id == "c" ? "Cat" : ($id == "d" ? "Dog" : "Others")));
```

Answer (score 3):

From the notes on ternary operators: http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php

```
<?php
// on first glance, the following appears to output 'true'
echo (true?'true':false?'t':'f');

// however, the actual output of the above is 't'
// this is because ternary expressions are evaluated from left to right

// the following is a more obvious version of the same code as above
echo ((true ? 'true' : false) ? 't' : 'f');

// here, you can see that the first expression is evaluated to 'true', which
// in turn evaluates to (bool)true, thus returning the true branch of the
// second ternary expression.
?>
```

Answer (score 2):

#### Way #1

Use a `switch` instead and it also helps your code more readable..

```
switch($id)
{
    case "a":
        echo "Apple";
        break;
    
    case "b":
        echo "Bat";
        break;
    
    //Your code...
    
    //More code..
}
```

---

#### Way #2

You can also make use of `array_key_exists()`

```
$id = "a";
$arr = ["a"=>"Apple","b"=>"Bat"];
if(array_key_exists($id,$arr))
{
    echo $arr[$id]; //"prints" Apple
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try like

```
echo $id == "a" ? "Apple" : ($id == "b" ? "Bat" : $id == "c" ? "Cat" : $id == "d" ? "Dog" : "Others");
```

If the condition will false then only the remaining block that I have put within `()` will execute.

Answer (score 0):

try to make separate your conditions

```
echo ($id == "a" ? "Apple" : ($id == "b" ? "Bat" : $id == "c" ? "Cat" : $id == "d" ? "Dog" : "Others"));
```

else use `switch()` would be better

Answer (score 0):

Here it is :

```
<?php
$id = "a";
echo $id == "a" ? "Apple" : ($id == "b" ? "Bat" : $id == "c" ? "Cat" : $id == "d" ? "Dog" : "Others");
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Put else condition part in parenthesis :

```
echo $id == "a" ? "Apple" : ($id == "b" ? "Bat" : $id == "c" ? "Cat" : $id == "d" ? "Dog" : "Others");
```

Refer [operator precedence](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.precedence.php)